# Compare two strings add(empty space, commas, dots, etc) c++

Tags: c++, string, loops, text, alter

Hi there all I hope someone can help me out, I am trying to fix my string output, I get an output but its all mashed up into one long string no spaces etc, so I am trying to use the old string that was there before with commas spaces etc and replace them in the new one. I don't really know how to go about doing this I have tried this in c++ if I run the code below in my program it will crash on me I have no idea how to fix it.

```
string input2 = "chq pste uwdn or mfwiejjne
u aaul mvabe mrv po zso, jnp kg co urfrsrvwn,
azh s bmmpd lanmf kuupv chqvw, xf opsh azh ojtfpwb mmhw;
wizi tnaz vgfs imdu i tenn ttijn, a tmnn fav lqe tsfny niw,
jnp paee mpgwe ur lqe niw uogh yuapi.
swd u wzjlx lsee esen pqeun ttijn, fav hnaoi uxmqw vaobtawg epgf,
ddshyizk xaoy xzn vqmdb or xzn mavfrns xg fhqvw chq gjrcwil bizkk;
chqvw vipraphf’w sul m kdrmyij, jnp rgxn m tmapxi yuoi,
efm ehifrns jmul aj lqe xmfwef’w ornsw.
a fixp saiei swd ss fxw, rsj jlieqb nukzc azh vjy
u lwjr xecn wmxwa lmthrns aach xso bogrvb bk xzn stsjn;
wtmdn i exswd ar lqe dssmwmc, ga oz xzn pmzwvezxk prqc,
a qemv ac iz xzn dqih qemvl’b cavw.";


string result = "THELAKEISLEOFINNISFREEIWILLARISEANDGONOWANDGOTOINNISFREEANDASMALLCAB
INBUILDTHEREOFCLAYANDWATTLESMADENINEBEANROWSWILLIHAVETHEREAHIVEFORTH
EHONEYBEEANDLIVEALONEINTHEBEELOUDGLADEANDISHALLHAVESOME
PEACETHEREFORPEACECOMESDROPPINGSLOWDROPPINGFROMTHEVEILSOFTHEMORNINGTOWHERETHE
CRICKETSINGSTHEREMIDNIGHTSALLAGLIMMERANDNOONAPURPLEGLOWANDEVENINGFULLOFTHELINNET
SWINGSIWILLARISEANDGONOWFORALWAYSNIGHTANDDAYIHEARLAKEWATERLAPPINGWITHLOWSOUNDSB
YTHESHOREWHILEISTANDONTHEROADWAYORONTHEPAVEMENTSGREYIHEARITINTHEDEEPHEARTSCORE";

string original = input2; //original unchanged text with spaces, commas etc
string tempResult = result; //the new output without spaces, commas, dots etc
string fixed = ""; //string to be altered with spaces, commas etc
int originalSize = input2.size();
int i = 0, j = 0;

for(i, j; i < originalSize ;i++)
{
  if(isalnum(original[i]) || !original[i] == ' ')
{
  fixed += tempResult[j];
  j++;
}
else
{
  fixed += tempResult[j];
}
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for your code.

Comment: Most probably you are going out of range with one of the `[]` subscript operations. Use a debugger to find out where exactly and why this happens.

Comment: i have done that but its gets the error when it reaches first space in the text and its suppose to add a space from the old string then it crashes i also forgot this "int originalSize = input2.size();"

Comment: Original string = "u aaul mvabe mrv po zso, jnp kg co urfrsrvwn,"; tempString =      "WILLARISEANDGONOWANDGOTOINNISFREEANDAS"; im trying to take out the spaces from the original and insert them into the new one altered one

Comment: Please don't give additional information for your question in comments (especially not code), edit your question instead!

Comment: Sorry i apologise its my first time asking on this forum i have provided more understandable code this time. Thank you regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in the comments, providing a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would have made it easier to understand your question, but I think I understand what you're trying to do. Making minimal modifications to your code, one solution might be this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

string original = "xxxx, x xxxxx, xx x xxxxxx xxxxxxxx.";
string letters = "ThisIthinkisabetterquestion";
string desired = "This, I think, is a better question.";

int main()
{
    string fixed;
    int i, j;
    int originalSize = original.size();

    for(i=j=0; i < originalSize ;i++)
    {
        if(!isalnum(original[i]))
        {
          fixed += original[i];
        }
        else
        {
          fixed += letters[j++];
        }
    }
    cout << fixed << endl;
    cout << desired << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi there Edward this is exactly what I've been looking for, but somehow it does not work on mine it gives me the same exception that states "c > -1 && c <= 255" would that be that my string is too long? how could I overcome that? Regards Paul.